# Change Directory with Wildcard Redirect using RedirectMatch not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use a `RedirectMatch` to redirect all files under one directory to the main directory:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/question/.*$ https://www.sample.com/
```

So that if I have a URL like `www.sample.com/question/what-day-is-it`
It will automatically redirect to `www.sample.com/what-day-is-it`

The problem is when I put in the `RedirectMatch` like above, it redirects all URLs to the homepage: `www.sample.com/question/what-day-is-it` to `www.sample.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else had the same problem, a simple `Redirect 301 /question /` did the trick.